# differences running jqmobile from server vs local

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've taken over working on a jqueryMobile/phonegap app. 
When I run it from the source file://location_to_index.html in firefox (chrome has Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors), the page loads fine and runs.

I've packaged the site to run on heroku as a static site using rackup, 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby

When I try to run this page locally from `http://192.168.0.0.1:9292`, the page loads, but I get the following error

```
An unexpected error has occurred: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'changePage' of undefined
```

I've seen a few comments about how to initiate jQueryMobile with changePage and live instead of document ready, but I've got the page running from file, so I don't know why that would be any different than running from a server.

my init functions are

```
var jqMobilePreInit = function() {
    jQuery(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        jQuery.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
        jQuery.mobile.initializePage = false;
        jQuery.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select, input, fieldset, textarea, a, button ";
    });
};
var jqInit = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // only run if not inside phonegap. otherwise its done by phonegap
        if (window.device == null) {
            appInit();
        }
    }, 750);
};
```

the app init leads to a function where the historyStack is built and it calls an ajax page to load the requests and add them to the history.

```
    loadExternalPage(pp[0], function(extLoaded) {
                     setUpPage(pp[0], pp, false); // set up page
        jQuery.mobile.changePage(jQuery("#" + pp[0])); // call switch
    });
```

Any suggestions?